# Export the logs into a Text file for Oracle SQL "update" script using perl script

Tags: sql, database, oracle, perl

I have coded a perl script which connects to Oracle database and updates the data. The execution of perl script and connections to Database works fine.

But, I want to export the logs of the updated data into a Temporary Text file. Please suggest a solution. Below is my code,

```
use strict;
use DBD::Oracle;
use DBI;

my $driver = "Oracle";
my $database = "host=xxxxx;port=xxx;sid=xxxx";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:$database";
my $userid = "xxxxxx";
my $password = "xxxxx";

# Database Connection
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password,{RaiseError => 1}) or die "Can't connect to the Database: $DBI::errstr";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE XXXX SET ABCD=1233 WHERE LOGIN BETWEEN SYSDATE-24*30 and SYSDATE-12*30") or die "$DBI::errstr";

$sth->execute() or die "couldn't execute statementn$!";
$sth->rows;

# End of Program
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose to replace

```
$sth->execute() or die "couldn't execute statementn$!";
```

by

```
unless ( $sth->execute() ) {
    open LOGFILE, ">>", /tmp/logs/perl.log or die "Could not open logfile\n";              
    print LOGFILE $ora->errstr;
    close LOGFILE; 
    die "couldn't execute statementn$!";
 }
```

Comment: I have replaced as suggested above,`unless ( $sth->execute() ){`
    `open (LOGFILE, '>>', 'perl.log') or die "Could not open logfile\n";`
   `print LOGFILE $ora->errstr;`
    `close LOGFILE;`
   `die "couldn't execute statementn$!";`        but the file is not getting generated. As i felt like the data is not being fed into the File.

Comment: Maybe do the same for `$dbh->prepare`